# mvn integration-test command pulls in unwanted unit tests for execution

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

When I run `mvn test` it executes unit tests only but when I run `mvn integration-test` it executes both unit test and integration test even after configuring the `maven-failsafe-plugin` and excluding the `*Test.java` file. Not sure what I am missing here. Also worth mentioning that I have not put in `maven-surefire-plugin` in my pom.xml. Not sure if that is creating this problem. Please guide.

**pom.xml**

```
    <!-- Integration tests -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>                
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**Unit Test Class File:**

```
 com.study.jenkins.ut.MyUnitTest.java
```

**Integration Test Class File:**

```
com.study.jenkins.it.PageIT.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `maven-surefire-plugin` is part of the lifecycle, which is always bound to the `test`-phase for Java projects. Calling `integration-test` means that all lifecycle-phases up to the `integration-test` phase are executed. So the MyUnitTest will always be executed (which is a good thing).

Your includes/excludes have no effect, these are already the defaults for the `maven-failsafe-plugin`, see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes

Comment: I could run just the integration tests using "mvn failsafe:integration-test"

Comment: Don't forget to add `failsafe:verify`, because the `integration-test` goal will only run the tests and gather the results, the `verify` goal will actually evaluate the results and check if there are failures.